# Is the element (345)(67) even or odd?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Q. Is the element (345)(67) even or odd?

So by definition, a permutation is called even if it is a product of an even number of transpositions, and vice versa for odd.

So (345)(67)=(35)(34)(67)

which is three transpositions making it odd.

There is a theorem in my book that says the product of an even permutation and an odd permutation is odd.

Does theorem work for this case? And is this theorem always reliable; meaning, would it work for any problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does. Because (345) is an even permutation, as your factoring of it into (35)(34) shows. So you have an even perm and an odd perm, making an odd per.

And yes, the theorem works for all problems. That's what it means to be a theorem: the statement is true whenever the hypotheses hold.

One small hint: it's tempting to say that $(345)$ is odd because...well...it's a list of an *odd* number (i.e., three) items. Don't get fooled into thinking that! It's not the definition of "odd" for permutations.

Comment: Ah! Thanks! I was actually thinking in that sense that (345) is odd cause it has three numbers. I'll make sure not to think like that! So either way, you still have to change the permutation into transpositions to show if its even or odd?

Comment: That's right. (After some practice, you may not need to do so any more...once you detect a pattern or two.)